# Geometric explanation of Inverse Transform Sampling

Tags: probability, statistics

I am familiar with the mathematical setup. Given the CDF of a distribution, we can sample from it using inverse transform sampling as follows,

1) sample u uniformly from a uniform disibution.

2) Find x such that CDF(x)=u.

The math checks out, but I want a interpretation in terms of area under the curve.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you do with inverse transform sampling is that you generate a number between $0$ and $1$. Let's call this realization $u$. If you draw a horizontal line at $y=u$, then the next step in the cumulative distribution is your sample.

Here's a plot that might help illustrate it:

[image]

This is for a Geometric distribution that starts at $0$ and with $p=0.25$. When I generated $u$, I got that $u=0.27$. For this distribution, $$Pr(X\leq 0)=0.25<u=0.27 < Pr(X\leq 1)=0.4375$$ so the random sample is $x=1$. This is marked by the red dot in the plot - it's the next $x$ after the horizontal line, which is the uniform distribution generated number.